# how to sove chinese garbled with ajax request in jquery.validate.js remote function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

Example:name = 资源

```
rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                     url: location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/'))+"/resourceName/check/exists",
                     dataType: "text", 
                     beforeSend: function(req) { req.setRequestHeader ("contentType", "text / html; charset = uft-8"); },
                     type: "GET"
                  }
            },
            url: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            },
            menu_id: "required"
        }
```

In my controller i got the name but it is something like èµæº ,how can i solve the problem?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resourceName/check/exists", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void isResourceNameExists(HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name)
            throws IOException {
        name = new String (name.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"); 
        response.setContentType ("text / text; charset = UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding ("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(
                String.valueOf(resourceService.findResourcesByName(name)
                        .isEmpty()));
    }
```

Comment: Could this be your problem `charset = uft-8"`? UTF-8.

Comment: And this looks superfluous `name = new String (name.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"); `. You are converting a String to byte[] and back to String using the same encoding scheme.

Comment: BTW, the two chinese characters have unicode \u8d44 and \u6e90 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by `name = new String(name.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"utf-8");`